# Spyder retrieve hidden IPython console

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Sometimes when I use Spyder and that I press the wrong button or when the computation is too intensive I have my current IPython console that litteraly vanish from my screen. So I open another one with console->open IPython console but the other one seems to be still active somehow.
Is there a way to force the display of the ones that have disappeared ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press ctrl+shift+I for displaying ipython console
or

Its a kind of workaround, Go to view and click on **Attached Console Window (debugging)** and then open a new console it shows the hidden console.

Comment: Well that is what I did so basically if I still cannot see anything it is because the kernel has crashed somehow and that the former IPython died I suppose. Thanks for your help.